# XSLT Transformation: newTransformer versus newTemplates with respect to class loading

Tags: xslt

My program has a multi-threading environment where I don't have control over spawning of threads, but some framework that I use has the control.

I found that the use of `newTemplates(XSLstreamsource)` is threadsafe, while `newTransformer(XSLstreamsource)` is not. But what I would like to know, really, is if there is any difference between these two with respect to loading of the implementation class in to JVM.

The problem that I am facing now is that every `newTransformer` call (in the various threads) loads the class, thus occupying the perm gen memory portion highly.

I would like to know if `newTemplates` would load the class only once, as against `newTransformer`. Or are there solutions to avoid the class getting loaded every time?

Answer (score 1):

Think of the "`Templates`" object as the compiled stylesheet, and the "`Transformer`" object as the stylesheet loaded and ready to execute.

You want to reuse the `Templates` object if you possibly can, so you only compile the stylesheet once, but creating a new `Transformer` for each transformation works perfectly well and there's very little point in reusing it (it's permitted to reuse it serially, that is, to start another `transform()` call after the previous one finishes; but there are no benefits in doing so.)

Comment: Thank you Michael and Mads. So, I figure that the two does not have any difference with respect to Perm Gen memory Consumption? Am I right? by the way, would using SAXTransformer result in lesser Perm Gen Consumption?

Comment: If you're concerned about memory, presumably that's because you are processing large source documents. Typically the source document tree will be owned by the Transformer, and assuming you are only doing one transformation on the document, it will be garbage collected when the Transformer is released. Using a SAXTransformer is unlikely to make any difference; the processor will still build a tree in memory.